# Changing to grey SHADER moves all sprites a pixel or two in LibGDX

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I have the below fragment shader. It changes the video to grey when I press a certain button. It works but there is one pb: all the sprites go down a few pixels after the shader is set. It seems the whole screen is offset in the downward direction with a few pixels

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
precision mediump int;
#else
#define highp;
#endif

uniform sampler2D u_texture;

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

const vec3 grayChange = vec3(0.299*0.4, 0.587*0.4, 0.114*0.4);

void main() {
    vec4 texColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord);
    vec3 grayCol = vec3(dot(texColor.rgb, grayChange));
    gl_FragColor = vec4(grayCol.r, grayCol.g, grayCol.b, texColor.a * v_color.a);
}
```

Here's the vertex shader:

```
uniform mat4 U_WORLD_VIEW;

attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;
attribute vec4 a_color;

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main() {
    gl_Position = U_WORLD_VIEW * vec4(a_position.xy,0,1);
    v_texCoord = a_texCoord0;
    v_color = a_color;
}
```

Comment: Are you using the same vertex shader for non-grey rendering?  Can you include that vertex shader if not?  (Or just point to the default one in the libgdx source.)

Comment: Shouldn't the last parameter in your modified position be 0 instead of 1?

Comment: @P.T, I use no shader for normal rendering

Comment: @Tenfour04, `gl_Position = U_WORLD_VIEW * vec4(a_position.xy,0,1);` gives me the same result as `gl_Position = U_WORLD_VIEW * a_position;`. Also, if I put 0 so we have `vec4(a_position.xy,0,0);` I just get a BLACK image.

Comment: How are you setting `U_WORLD_VIEW `? Why not use `spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix()` and then the built-in uniform `u_projTrans`?

Comment: @gogonapel Ah, but you do use a shader for normal rendering.  Its just hidden in Libgdx:  https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.java#L124